# Posting to a friends wall using the facebook API. C#

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have the following code.

```
 public void PostToWall(string message, string targetId)
    {
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = message;
        parameters.target_id = targetId;
        dynamic result = _fbApp.Api("/me/feed", parameters, HttpMethod.Post);
    }
```

Which works fine when the targetId is the id of the user authenticated.

However, when targetId is that of one of the authenticated users friends it doesn't work.

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect because you're trying to post to your feed, not the friend - `/me/feed`

The FB GraphAPI specifies that you POST to `http://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed`.

Comment: tried that before with no luck. I'm thinking the target_id parameter is in the API for a reason. But I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: You might want to switch to the official FB C# API. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/ It appears to be a thin wrapper around the GraphAPI. If you look, the GraphAPI for posting to a feed doesn't even have target_id - that's something from the old APIs

Comment: You're totally right.... don't know what I was trying while I was doing it before. Easy to think yourself around in circles.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you, but you can't actually do this.
Facebook has change the privacy settings, so that you can't access your friends wall using an app
Please find the relevant info here
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/
(look for the change of February 6th)

Comment: I would also add a reference URL to cite your source, if you have one.